# scorm 1.2 bookmarking trouble

Tags: scorm

Please help me...

I need to bookmark scorm 1.2 courses developed in articulate and adobe presenter 7.

I'm using cmi.suspend_data to do that...

Its working fine for articulate courses, but for adobe presenter 7, its giving different cmi.suspend_data values for different attempts.

Even, i tried with cmi.core.lesson_location.. but no use..

always its going to first slide for every attempt..

so, i want to know the process to bookmark a adobe presenter 7 course.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a problem with Adobe Presenter. Is there an exit button that they are expecting you to use? Does it vary based on how you close the content? Have you tried it in a different LMS? If you try it in [SCORM Test Track](http://www.scorm.com/scorm-solved/test-track/) and post the debug logs, something might jump out.

Answer (score 0):

You must set cmi.exit to 'suspend' when your SCO exits, or the LMS won't restore your suspend or location values.

Comment: thankyou Ishmael,
i didnot find any cmi.exit
i'm working in scorm 1.2 , i think u mean cmi.core.exit
Anyway,
cmi.core.exit was set suspend only.

Comment: My problem is cmi.suspend_data is not the same data for same slide in  different login attempts...

Comment: Let me explain u more clearly,
In d 1st attempt,
after 3rd slide opens,i got cmi.suspend_data as
7C000000001110000000000000AA000A
then,i stored this data and returned in getvalue(cmi.suspend_data).
so,now course should go to 3rd slide when i open it again,
in my 2nd attempt,
i reopened that course and it started from 1st slide again,
and i found that for the same 3rd slide i'm getting a different cmi.suspend_data
and I'm unable to figure out, 
how to resume the course with different cmi.suspend_data for the same 3rd slide...

i hope u can understand my problem..
please get back to this soon..